# IOS: How to Symbolicate the custom framework

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash

I have an App which has a custom framework. When my app crashes, I could symbolicate the crash log in which I can only symbolicate the symbols in my app. But I want to symbolicate the framework as well. And I cannot create or find where the dsym file for the custom framework.

**CrashLog:**

```
      Incident Identifier: E2C7076A-78E1-4269-91D0-A2AA5CA33612
    CrashReporter Key:   7057b96f6b8938b54fe1ddecd38f89da2d16b752
    Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
    Process:             MyTestSuite [562]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/708341EB-76AB-4A0D-86E5-73DB875D26DA/MyTestSuite.app/MyTestSuite
    Identifier:          com.econsys.TestSuite
    Version:             1 (1)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2016-09-23 15:41:43.43 +0530
    Launch Time:         2016-09-23 15:23:13.13 +0530
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.3 (13G34)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  3

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                  0x183ee2db0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x183547f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x183ee2cf8 +[NSException raise:format:] + 120
    3   Foundation                      0x1848602b0 -[NSMutableData(NSMutableData) replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:length:] + 300
    4   DevSDK                          0x10010ff28 0x10009c000 + 474920
    5   DevSDK                          0x10013d234 0x10009c000 + 660020
    6   DevSDK                          0x10013d474 0x10009c000 + 660596
    7   ExternalAccessory               0x18f682a90 -[EAOutputStream _streamEventTrigger] + 420
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x183e9d7c8 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 1216
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x183e9909c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x183e98b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x183e96830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x183dc0c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    13  Foundation                      0x1847d0cfc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
    14  Foundation                      0x184826030 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
    15  DevSDK                          0x10010de48 0x10009c000 + 466504
    16  DevSDK                          0x10010de74 0x10009c000 + 466548
    17  Foundation                      0x1848b7e4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x183b47b28 _pthread_body + 156
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x183b47a8c _pthread_start + 156
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x183b45028 thread_start + 4
```

I want to symbolicate the lines 4, 5, 6 in the backtrace.

Help me on this pls.